# When i call a method nothing happens

Tags: ios, xcode, nsuserdefaults

I have a class where i store my methods:

**.h** file:

```
   #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SessionController : NSObject

-(void) addSession :(NSString *)userName
      tipulContului:(NSString *)tipCont;
-(void) destroySession : (NSString *) userName;
-(NSString *) getSessionUsername;
-(NSString *) getSessionTipCont;
@end
```

**.m** file:

```
  #import "SessionController.h"

    @implementation SessionController

    -(void) addSession : (NSString *)userName
         tipulContului :(NSString *)tipCont
    {
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setObject:userName forKey:@"SessionUsername"];
        [defaults setObject:tipCont forKey:@"SessionTipCont"];
        NSLog(@"------------------------------------------------");
        //NSLog(@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation]);
        NSLog(@"%@", userName);

        [defaults synchronize];
    }
    -(void) destroySession : (NSString *) userName
    {
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults removeObjectForKey:@"SessionUsername"];
        [defaults removeObjectForKey:@"SessionTipCont"];
        [defaults synchronize];
    }
    -(NSString *) getSessionUsername
    {
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        //  verificam existenta utilizatorului
        if([defaults stringForKey:@"SessionUsername"]!=nil && ![[defaults stringForKey:@"SessionUsername"] isEqual:@""]){
            return [defaults stringForKey:@"SessionUsername"];
        }
        else
            return nil;
    }
    -(NSString *) getSessionTipCont
    {
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        //  verificam existenta Tipului de cont
        if([defaults objectForKey:@"SessionTipCont"]!=nil && ![[defaults stringForKey:@"SessionTipCont"] isEqual:@""]){
            return [defaults stringForKey:@"SessionTipCont"];
        }
        else
            return nil;
    }
    @end
```

Than i call call the method from an external class like this

```
SessionController *sessionController;
    [sessionController addSession:name tipulContului:type];
```

But  the **NSLog** from the `addSession` method isn't called and the values that i send to the method aren't stored, it compiles and i don't have any warnings, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hyphen before the method name indicates the method is an "instance" method.  You'll need to instantiate the object to utilize these.  You're almost doing this.  Try:

```
 SessionController *sessionController = [[SessionController alloc] init];
```

Comment: *Or just alloc in some circumstances* and those circumstances are?

Comment: The circumstance to only call `alloc` is never.

Comment: // Removed bone-headed comment.

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize your sessionController object

```
SessionController* sessionController = [[SessionController alloc] init];
```